# Show key value pair in table using meteor and mongo db

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In mongodb  i have json values like and it is not fixed. Some time it will be only 2 or 3 and sometime it will be very large.

```
  {"_id" : "p83oZAo7fdhNuDD34",
"Active Template Name" : "Windows Mobile",
"ProductId" : "456",
"Subcategory" : "on",
"Size" : "on",
"Material" : "A",
"Price" : "2345",
"Combo Id" : "67u",
"Color" : "red",
"Status" : "Pending"
},
{
  "_id" : "p83oZAo7fdhNuDD34",
"Material" : "A",
"Price" : "2345",
"Combo Id" : "67u",
"Color" : "red",
"Status" : "Pending"
}
```

I want to show all keys like (id, Active Template Name, ProductID .......) as table header and values (p83oZAo7fdhNuDD34,Windows Mobile,456 .......) in tbody.

I am not getting the exact way to perform this in meteor. My collection name is products and Html code is bellow.

```
    <template name="productvalue">
     <table>

     </table>
    </template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `{{#each}}` block helper to iterate over your collection products.

```
<template name="productvalue">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Active Template Name</th>
      <th>ProductId</th>
      [...]
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {{#each products}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{_id}}</td>
          <td>{{activeTemplateName}}</td>
          <td>{{ProductId}}</td>
          [...]
        </tr>
      {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

You also need to define helpers to rename the problematic keys containing invalid Spacebars characters.

```
Template.productvalue.helpers({
  products: function(){
    return Products.find();
  },
  activeTemplateName: function(){
    return this["Active Template Name"];
  },
  [...]
});
```

Comment: Brother actually this json is dynamic. it is not sure that every time it will has the same value. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display a table with all the possible properties in the header, and each row with each column filled or not whether the property is defined or not for the document in that row, then you will need to:

1. Ahead of time (in `onCreated` or `onRendered`), find *all* possible properties for your dataset, order them, and store them in a "header" object accessible to your helpers. (either in `Session` or using a [reactive variable](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar_pkg)) Make it reactive if necessary, using `this.autorun()`.
2. Then, do the same as above, except just returning the stored ordered list for `tableHeader`
3. And for `rowContent`, iterate over your stored header and fill an array with empty strings for each undefined field in the current document

Example:

```
function getHeader(products) {
  var header = {};
  for (var key in products) {
    for (var property in products[key]) {
        header[property] = true;
    }
  }
  return Object.keys(header);
}

Template.productvalue.onRendered(function () {
  var products = Products.find().fetch();
  Session.set('header', getHeader(products));
  this.autorun(function () {
    var products = Products.find().fetch();
    Session.set('header', getHeader(products));
  });
});

Template.productvalue.helpers({
  'tableHeader': function () {
    return Session.get('header');
  },
  'rowContent': function (document) {
    var row = [];
    var header = Session.get('header');
    for (var key in header) {
      row.push(document[header[key]] || "");
    }
    return row;
  }
});
```

And in template:

```
<template name="productvalue">
 <table>
  <thead>
   {{#each tableHeader}}
    <th>{{this}}</th>
   {{/each}}
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   {{#each products}}
    <tr>
     {{#each rowContent this}}
      <td>{{this}}</td>
     {{/each}}
    </tr>
   {{/each}}
  </tbody>
 </table>
</template>
```

I still recommend [using a reactive variable](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/scoped-reactivity) instead of `Session`, but the demonstration is complicated enough as it is.

Comment: Brother actually this json is dynamic. it is not sure that every time it will has the same value. I edited my question.

Comment: My answer answers just that in the end.

Comment: Removed the first half then.